# How to get href from tag <a> (html) by BS4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Hie there!
I can't get href from tag  in BS4. That is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-jeep/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)                        AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36', 'accept':'*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r 

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all(class_='proposition_area')
    cars=[]
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title': item.find('h3', class_='proposition_name').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': item.find('a', class_='proposition_link').getAttribute("href")              
        })
    print(cars)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else: 
        print('error')  
parse()
```

output:

```
'link': item.find('a', class_='proposition_link').getAttribute("href")
```

Error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'
```

Comment: `item.find('a', class_='proposition_link')` is returning `None`

Comment: That means the element you're looking for isn't in the HTML.

Comment: yes, and I can't fix it

Comment: Correct, if it's _not there_, you can't fix it.

Comment: Are you looking at the HTML in your browser, or are you looking at it in `curl` or your Python interpreter? One very common problem we see here is people trusting their browsers to be showing exactly what the remote server returns.

Comment: ...however, very often there's Javascript code or DOM fixups changing what the browser shows, so it's not an accurate representation of what your software needs to be written to look for.

Comment: ? I don't understand. I just want to get href from tag <a>. Is that html?

Comment: The tag is HTML, but the question is if the HTML is there in what the server gives you, or if JavaScript code being run in your web browser _creates_ the `<a>` tag.

Comment: If it's JavaScript running in the browser that creates the tag, then the tag doesn't exist without a web browser in use, so bs4 (and anything else that isn't a web browser with javascript support) can't see it.

Comment: Anyhow, it's easy to test that. _Print your HTML in the Python code_ and inspect it, and see if it really contains the elements you're trying to find. (In this case, `print(html.text)` will do the trick).

Comment: thank you! And how I need to get the link from it?

Comment: ...so, having done that test above, it looks like the HTML that the server returns _does_ include the relevant item, so you aren't facing the specific issue I mentioned.

Comment: ...rather, the issue is simply that none of the `proposition_area`s in that page contain a `proposition_link`. They _do_ have a span with `class=link`; maybe that's what you wanted?

Comment: Anyhow, if they have a `proposition_link` in the web browser, it's JavaScript doing that. You don't have JavaScript without a web browser; you can't rely on anything it does.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems:

1. You are doing `items = soup.find_all(class_='proposition_area')` and later looping over that class to search for the class `proposition_area` with:

   ```
   for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title': item.find('h3', class_='proposition_name').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': item.find('a', class_='proposition_link').get("href")
        })
   ```

   the `item.find('a', class_='proposition_link')` is *not within* the class `proposition_area` which you are looping for, so, instead do:

   ```
   items = soup.find_all(class_='proposition')
   ```

2. Don't use the `.getAttribute()` method, instead, use `.get()`.

Here's a fully working example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://auto.ria.com/newauto/marka-jeep/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36', 'accept':'*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all(class_='proposition')
    cars=[]
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title': item.find('h3', class_='proposition_name').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': item.find('a', class_='proposition_link').get("href")
        })
    print(cars)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('error')
parse()
```

Output:

```
[{'title': 'Jeep Gladiator 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-gladiator-1862595.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1859603.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1863650.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1842428.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Renegade 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-renegade-1838198.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1853604.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Wrangler 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1838190.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1811781.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Wrangler 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1857232.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Wrangler 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1860925.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1836192.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Renegade 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-renegade-1857781.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1838297.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Wrangler 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1860927.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Wrangler 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1860588.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Gladiator 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-gladiator-1856629.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Renegade 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-renegade-1857246.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1857805.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Grand Cherokee 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-grand-cherokee-1829808.html'}, {'title': 'Jeep Wrangler 2021', 'link': '/newauto/auto-jeep-wrangler-1862123.html'}]
```